# Rational Points on Elliptic Curves

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

I have this homework problem: Can there be an elliptic curve, view as a projective curve, with no rational points with at least one 0 as a coordinate?

Comment: What about the point at infinity?

Comment: What is the definition of an elliptic curve in your context ? Do you have a special form to follow or would a genus 1 curve with a general equation be ok ?

Comment: If an arbitrary form of genus 1 curve is ok, consider the projective curve with equation: $X^2\,Y+X\,Z^2+Y^2\,Z+X^3+Y^3+Z^3$. Check that it has no rational points with at least one $0$ coordinate. Hint: consider points with coordinates in GF(2).

Comment: I am sorry! What I meant was "exactly one 0" as coordinate. Thank you.

Comment: My definition of elliptic curve (over the rational) is just smooth genus one curve with at least one rational point.

Comment: @jennifer, you can edit the question (link right below the tags) if you'd like to change "at least one" to "exactly one". That way the question should bounce back to the front page so people see it again as well.

Answer (score 2):

Sure: take an elliptic curve over $\mathbf Q$ with trivial Mordell-Weil group, for example the curve $11a2$ in Cremona's tables (with equation $y^2+y=x^3−x^2−7820x−263580$), and use a projective transformation (over $\mathbf Q$) to send the point at infinity to $(1:1:1)$.